# how to hide a page from being seen in wordpress backend and frontend

Tags: wordpress

In my plugin i have created a custom template that prints a requested sidebar. and for running the code of this template i assigned a custom page to it (by calling update_metadata) .
Is it a good idea for getting content of a specific sidebar into Ajax call ?
Now my problem is that WORDPRESS shows it in the dashboard and front page , and after searching i have not found any easy to understand solution for Hiding a page completely so only can be accessed by its id .
Can any one tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Whats the point of create a page if you can't access to that page in admin area?

Comment: it only prints the content of a dynamic sidebar , then i get the content of that page with a Ajax call.

Comment: The feature i think you are looking for is called virtual page, meaning you can catch a query for a plugin and output a response without needing to create a page at all.

Comment: yes , if that is possible . but for calling function dynamic_sidebar i think we need to run WORDPRESS core is it not true ?

Comment: also there is another PHP feature called object buffering, with this feature we can store the output of a php file in server . but that feature is disabled in some shared hostings , and i don't want use that at all. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are going about this the wrong way. You can create a function that can create anything that can be created on a wordpress page.

But if you really must you can create a page outside of the database, etc:

```
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rule');
function add_rewrite_rule(){
   // add_rewrite_rule(REGEX url, location, priority (i.e. top is before other rewrite rules)
   // I created a custom post type for this plugin called market -- replace post_type with whatever you want 
   //basically tell wordress to add a query var if sidebar is added to url.
   add_rewrite_rule('^sidebar?','index.php?is_sidebar_page=1&post_type=market','top');
}

// register a query var
add_action('query_vars','market_set_query_var');
function market_set_query_var($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'is_sidebar_page');
    return $vars;
}

// associate a template with your quer_var 
add_filter('template_include', 'market_include_template', 1000, 1);
function market_include_template($template){
    if(get_query_var('is_sidebar_page')){
       $new_template = (theme or plugin path).'/pages/yourpage.php'; // change this path to your file 
    if(file_exists($new_template))
        $template = $new_template;
    } 
return $template;
}
```

This will not be a page that will be in the admin section or in any query that relates to pages but someone could of course navigate to this page. But as i said above you would be better to create a function to create your sidebar. If you want a seperate file to handle the "view" you use require_once 'filename'; a file and keep your functions area free of html.

If you are creating functions in a wordpress plugin dont forget many functions may not be available until later in the load process. Use add_action() if you run into any undefined functions

edit:

you are loading wordpress before you get to the template so you have all the functions. (google wp load for more info) + get_header() / get_footer() will also load a few things like css, etc. I had a small typo in the code above, fixed that but basically what you are doing is telling wordpress if someone lands on www.example.com/sidebar to apply a query_var (rewrite rule). Wordpress will look  up its saved vars (final function) and return the template assoc. The 2nd function just registers the var.

You also have wp_functions in any file you create and include in a plugin, etc hence why you can create a file that does exactly the same as this page.

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer , but i have few questions . is it not better to make a page (because this way i can access all WORDPRESS features not only sidebars or specific feature) ?   also can you please tell me more about the function that you said ?

Comment: In above code how WORDPRESS understands which file should be loaded for current URL ?

Comment: hi, i edited my answer with a bit more infor for you!