# wordpress .htaccess rewrite url

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am developing quiz section for my wordpress site. I have W3 total cache installed on my site.
I want to put quiz on

http://www.example.com/quiz/seo-friendly-title/id

and rewrite htaccess to redirect the url to

http://www.example.com/quiz?title=seo-friendly-title&quiz-id=id

The quiz section is developed as wordpress template and a blank page is made using this template.

This is .htaccess I wrote.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^quiz/([\w\d\-]+)/(\d]+)$ quiz?title=$1&quiz-id=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Any form of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you go to settings and permalinks?  if yes and its not what you want have a look here

[how to hide a page from being seen in wordpress backend and frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985550/how-to-hide-a-page-from-being-seen-in-wordpress-backend-and-frontend/24985961#24985961)

```
add_action('init', 'a_add_rewrite_rule');
function a_add_rewrite_rule(){
// add_rewrite_rule(REGEX url, location, priority (i.e. top is before other rewrite rules)
// I created a custom post type for this plugin called market -- replace post_type with whatever you want 
//basically tell wordress to add a query var if sidebar is added to url.
add_rewrite_rule('^sidebar?','index.php?is_sidebar_page=1&post_type=market','top');
}

// register a query var
add_action('query_vars','market_set_query_var');
function market_set_query_var($vars) {
array_push($vars, 'is_sidebar_page');
return $vars;
}

// associate a template with your quer_var 
add_filter('template_include', 'market_include_template', 1000, 1);
function market_include_template($template){
if(get_query_var('is_sidebar_page')){
   $new_template = (theme or plugin path).'/pages/yourpage.php'; // change this path to your file 
if(file_exists($new_template))
    $template = $new_template;
} 
return $template;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where can I put this snippet? Inside /theme/function.php?

Comment: yes that will do! make sure you change post type in rewrite-- you can use "page" as post type also.

Comment: I posted question again. I used already used page type and rewrote the rule as you requested but no success. Can you check the code please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072613/add-rewrite-rule-wordpress-with-w3-total-cache

Comment: flush the rewrite rules -- go to settings permalinks and click on "save"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^quiz/seo-friendly-title/(.*)$ quiz?title=seo-friendly-title&quiz-id=$1 [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```