# Am I using Wordpress incorrectly?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I am new to web dev with WP. I just realized that I made my front page (it has a form to be filled out by a user) by putting the code for it in a php file (through CPanel) and using `<?php include() ?>` to use that php file in my index.php. However, I just noticed that WP has a Pages section where I can add code by simply surrounding it with `<code></code>`. What is the best practice here? Am I under-using the CMS that is Wordpress by not using this Pages section? Or is it ok to not use it?

Comment: worpress is for people who don't want to write code

Comment: Wp saves the text editor content into the db so it does not run inserted php (there are plugins for this but dont...). add_actions is the wordpress way, e.g. `add_action('init', 'post_handle_function');`  or use shortcodes to run your function. Or you can create custom page templates and post to the same file, etc.

Comment: @David by "run your function" do you mean entire forms?

Comment: @Dagon but can I mix and match? I've already written most of my main page's code in a php file. The goal of writing this main page myself was because there is a plugin I'd like to use but it doesn't look the way I'd like it to look. So I thought I'd make a form that will post to the plugin's form and submit. Can I use add_actions from here going forward?  Or should I just switch to using WP entirely?The main page has a navbar, 3 buttons, a form, some UI javascript (toggle forms...). It also has a field that I will need to add into the already existing plugin.

Comment: @Dagon and to top it all off, I will be integrating user-to-user payments with Braintree. What do you suggest is the best plan of attack?

Comment: If you want to add a form in WordPress, one of the most common ways would be to use a plugin like Ninja Forms or Gravity Forms. You can do a lot of stuff without writing any code, which is sort of the point of a CMS. If you want a very custom page, you should probably be creating a custom theme or plugin.

Comment: @ggkid2002 yes you can use shortcodes to output the form and handle the post action, when wp sees a shortcode, it will call the function and you can handle $_Post in there. It sounds like you might be making a application? If so, for performance reasons, you can use wp-rewrite to serve a normal php file (at least you will avoid using the db for content, title etc) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063087/wordpress-htaccess-rewrite-url/25063282#25063282

Comment: @David sorry to be so noob here, I just don't understand how to best approach my project. Would you care to converse via email or chat so I can explain my project and maybe you can provide some guidance as to how I should be going about this? It's a simple 3 page website (not including the casual stuff like TOS, Privacy Policy, etc...) that will allow for user to user transactions.

Answer (score -2):

you can use some pulgins to use php code in pages like "allow-php-in-posts-and-pages" . and if you want some php file then you have create a template for that and that temmplate should be add in wp-page .

Comment: As i mentioned above, dont do this...if users can insert posts, they can also store php functions.....e.g. `phpinfo()`